# defaultRecordTypeId on the User object is always null

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, getobjectinfo

I have been trying to get the defaultRecordTypeId on my LWC component to fetch some picklist values from the User object but it's always null. Understandably so, as no record types exist on the object. The documentation says I need to hardcode '012000000000000AAA' as the value for the recordTypeId but I want to avoid hardcoding the Id values in my component. Is there a way to get this working(including any solution with Apex)?

Answer (score 2):

`012000000000000AAA` for the "Master" RecordTypeId is actually the One Id It Is Okay To Hardcode. It's the same Id value across all Salesforce orgs/instances. In this case, it's not a shortcut in a code example that's meant to be replaced, it's hardcoded by the platform itself.

For readability and reuse, you could do something like adding an export to a utility component.

util.js

```js
export const masterRecordTypeId = '012000000000000AAA';
```

myLwc.js

```js
import { masterRecordTypeId } from 'c/util';
```

Addendum: as far as I know, this usage with LWC is the only place this value is really useful

Addendum 2:
For objects supported by the UI API the below should work if you have an `objectInfo` property wired to the getObjectInfo adapter

```js
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: PICKLIST_FIELD
})
picklistValues;
```

Comment: the addendum 2 code that you added to your response returns null as it doesn't work on the User object

Comment: Right- user object isn't UI API supported, I'll edit my answer to be more clear